# Rails ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

rarils 4.0.0
I'm trying to post a comments but I have an error:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in CommentsController#create 
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

```
def create
@comment = @article.comments.new(params[:comment]) #error point highlight this line

Parameters
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"zSq3KpEbucFQLa6XStEJ/I0+CpKPLFYcU/WGIdneeMg=",
 "comment"=>{"name"=>"g12345",
 "email"=>"g12345@12345.com",
 "body"=>"hello hello"},
 "commit"=>"Add",
 "article_id"=>"5"}
```

my comments/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.new], remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, :value => form_authenticity_token) %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit 'Add' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please post your `comments_controller` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4 uses strong parameters by default.  Do you have something like:

`params.require(:some_param).permit(...)`

or

`params.permit(:list, :of, :allowed, :params)`

in your `CommentsController`?

It would look something like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params) #error point highlight this line
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :email, :body)
  end

end
```

Comment: Thks CDub I don't have something like that in my Comments Controller. I only have as a private function : `code` def load_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

Comment: That's causing your issue.  See my example above, and eliminate whichever parameters you don't want to permit to mass assignment.